# JS/jQuery: Popupbox with options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes. I am using normal confirm boxes for my "did you mean firstname lastname?" with yes/no

I also have "Who of these did you mean:" and i want a popup/dialog for this too, where you can select one of the names you ment.

example so the popup would look like this:

```
Who did you mean?:
[ ] Bumb bam
[x] bim bum
[ ] bam bam
OK
```

Here's my code so far:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "misc/sendPM.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,

    success: function(stuff){

      if(typeof stuff == "object") { 
        var err = confirm(stuff.error);
        if(err){ // if you press ok on "did you mean ....?"
        alert('You pressed OK');
        }
```

Or if you have another idea on how to do this, please dont hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

Real browser dialogs are not intended to be customizable.  (I suppose you could go down the path of writing browser-specific extensions but that would be a huge waste of time...)

Consider showing a div that contains the user interface characteristics you need.
With jquery and css it's a straightforward

`yourDivName.show();` or `yourDivName.css('display','');`

on click of a contained response button it's just as easy to `hide()` the div.

Comment: But the div needs to contain the stuff.error (json content), and I need so you can click on the stuff error, and then use it

Comment: You can write the content of the div dynamically based on your json with $('#divid').html(...)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) instead of using the built-in alerts and popups. It's a nice full-featured plugin and I recommend it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html). It is a lot easier and configurable.